# Организовать очередь сообщений

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-kafka

Есть задача организовать систему передачи сообщений от клиента к менеджеру. Сейчас используется со стороны клиента ejabber , со стороны менеджера "своя система приема и отправки сообщений" . Думаю что лучше использовать для очередей, rocket, rabbit,kafka или просто базу данных? Задачи которые нужно решить: забирать сообщения по одному, очереди должны быть с приоритетом и должна быть выборка по тегам сообщения.

Comment: Очередь это FIFO. Если нужет приоритет и тэги, то можно извратиться на раскидывание сообщений по нескольким очередям, но проще это сделать на БД (если сообщений в очереди в один момент может быть много и(или) нужна их хорошая песистентность).

Answer (score 1):

Приоритеты и выборка -- это вообще слабые места очередей (на то они и очереди). Некоторые очереди поддерживают выборки, но обычно это относится к фильтрации сообщений во время потребления, а не к повторяющемуся выполнению запросов вида "дай мне такие-то сообщения". Я бы использовал базу данных для вашей задачи.

Kafka:

- не поддерживает приоритеты
- поддерживает выборку, но с использованием дополнительных средств (KSQL/KStream)

Rabbit:

- поддерживает приоритеты (со своими [тонкостями](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) однако)
- не поддерживает выборку

Rocket:

- не поддерживает приоритеты
- поддерживает выборку (однако [не более одного тэга на сообщение](http://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/filter-by-sql92-example/), либо нужно использовать SQL)